# How to compute for the capacitor to achieve a certain cut-off frequency?

Tags: capacitor, cutoff-frequency

[image: Circuit]

This is my task : "Select new values for C1 and C3 to get a lower cutoff frequency in the circuit shown above that is less than 20 Hz."

What I did first was choose 15Hz and then computed for the value of C1 and C2 by using 1/2piRC as shown in the following image:

[image: Solution]

Did I do it correctly? :(

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: No, because if you look at the input impedance, it is not really 6.8k, is it?

Comment: Your calculation of C1 is wrong. A tip: Re-draw the AC equivalent of the circuit and see what happens to R2 and R1.

Comment: @Justme  Ohhhh how can I fix it? Should I use R1||R2? So the R now to solve for C1 will be 73.53 micro ohms?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Umm they are in parallel????

Comment: @Rose yes, because at AC the 15VDC supply becomes 0V (GND). So R1's upper end goes to GND, which finally makes R1 and R2 in parallel. So all you should do is to re-calculate C1 using R = R1 || R2.

Comment: I don't understand how you are able to get 73.53 micro ohms as the result though as the circuit values are many decades larger, so double check your calculations. But otherwise you are on the right track, all resistances affecting the input node must be used to calculate the input impedance.

Comment: @Justme Thankyou!!! I did input the values incorrectly sigh R should be 3400 ohms which makes my C1 = 3.12 microF. Right?

Comment: @RohatKılıç  Thankyou for that clear explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

There are three cascaded high pass filters in that circuit.

This means that if you set the cut-off frequency (-3dB frequency) of all three RC filters to the same frequency using the standard formula fc = 1/(2*pi*RC) then the overall response of the complete circuit will be -9dB down at that frequency.

To get an overall circuit response of -3dB at the required frequency you must calculate the capacitor values to achieve a -3dB cut-off frequency of each of the three filters, using the equation in the paragraph above, and then double the values of all three capacitors.

By doubling the capacitor values we are making Capacitor Reactance, Xc = R/2 at the overall -3dB frequency.
Where R is the resistance associated with each filter.

Comment: The 1uF into 47k output filter has a cutoff frequency of 3.4Hz and it was not asked to be changed. Therefore the calculate the other filters at 20Hz then double the calculated values for their total to be about -3dB at less than 20Hz.